# Как связать карту с маркерами?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Требуется создать взаимосвязь между маркерами, представленными красными квадратами, и маркерами на карте. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на красные квадраты, соответствующий маркер на карте увеличивался в масштабе и в идеале выскакивало окно с адерсом.
http://jsfiddle.net/GnidaGnideGnid/sj2mX/23/

Comment: [Создание карты на сайте с адресами магазинов, с использованием API Яндекс.Карт версии 2.х][1].


  [1]: http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/sozdanie-karty-na-sajte-s-adresami-magazinov-s-ispolzovaniem-api-yandeks-kart-versii-2-x

Comment: Спасибо, но мне на своем уровне сложно разобраться, так как не знаю js. Можете подсказать?

Comment: в очередной раз удивляюсь людям которые не знают, учить не хотят и берут задания.

Comment: Это не задание). Учить JS плотно я буду в следующем месяце, на данном этапе главное html и css. А из JS мне осталось реализовать только это.

Comment: ну так там-же по ссылке пример с пояснениями, что ещё надо ? спрашивайте что непонятно в примере.